# Checking if same object exists in database when user tries to add new object

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have an application that users can take what courses they are taking and there is a many to many relationships between users and a course. Now when a user wants to add a course I want to check if they have not added the same course with the partial same value, for example, the same course code and year. Currently, my view is:

```
@login_required
def course_add(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CourseForm(request.POST or none)
        if form.is_valid():
            course = form.save(False)
            for c in request.user.courses.all():
                if course.course_code == c.course_code and course.course_year == c.course_year:
                    form = CourseForm
                    message = "It's seems you already have added this course please try again."
                    context = {
                        'form':form,
                        'message': message,
                    }
                return render(request,'home/courses/course_add.html', context)
            request.user.courses.add(course)
            return redirect('home:courses')
    else:
        form = CourseForm
    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request,'home/courses/course_add.html', context)
```

in my user model I have this line:

```
courses = models.ManyToManyField('home.Course',related_name='profiles')
```

an my course model is:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    course_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    course_year = models.IntegerField(('year'), validators=[MinValueValidator(1984), MaxValueValidator(max_value_current_year())])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_code
```

As you can see my intention is I don't want the user to be able to add a course if they're code and year exists regardless of the course name. How can I achieve this using `exists()` if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can run a query over `request.user.courses` to find that out, as follows:

```
if form.is_valid():
    course = form.save(False)
    has_coursed = request.user.courses \
        .filter(course_code=course.course_code, course_year=course.course_year).exists()
    if has_coursed:
        # ... all your other logic
```

You should avoid whenever it's possible to loop over a queryset (at least without having done a prefetch_related in case of ManyToMany relationships), since it implies performing extra database hits in most of times.